# I want something to be executed through django

Tags: python, django

I know this question was asked before, but none worked for me. I have this code that I want it to be executed when a button is clicked and a message is passed

```
import time
from sinchsms import SinchSMS

number = '+yourmobilenumber'
message = 'I love SMS!'

client = SinchSMS(your_app_key, your_app_secret)

print("Sending '%s' to %s" % (message, number))
response = client.send_message(number, message)
message_id = response['messageId']

response = client.check_status(message_id)
while response['status'] != 'Successful':
print(response['status'])
time.sleep(1)
response = client.check_status(message_id)
print(response['status'])
```

Basically, what I need is to add an input in a template "HTML File", this input get passed to the message variable in the code above, same with the number. I can easily do that with instances, but how can the below get executed when a button is clicked from the form in the template?

I'm kinda newbie in Django and still finding my way

Here is the [tutorial](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/sending-sms-python/) that explains how to make the python file, but execute it from the shell, not a django application.

I hope I was clear describing my problem and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The answer to this question will be very long, but I understand you may want pointers on where to start. If you want to build a web application with Django, follow their tutorial here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/
However, I recommend something easier like Flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#quickstart

Comment: I already have a Django app :D I just want to know how to make an option in my app that when it's clicked, the code gets executed

Comment: Since your code is a python code, you can write your code directly inside your view. Other cases are not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a form with a message field. In a view, you want to show that form and when the user press submit, you want to execute your script.

Here is some **pseudo**-code:

```
urls.py
url('^my-page/' my_views.my_view, name='my-page'),

forms.py
SmsForm(forms.Form):
    message = fields.CharField(...)


my_views.py
def my_view(request):
    form = SmsForm(data=request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            send_sms(form.cleaned_data['message'])    # do this last
            messages.success(request, "Success")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
    else:
        messages.warning(request, "Failure")

    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'form': form})
```

---

Check the Django documentation about urls, views, forms and messages and proceed step by step:

- 1. get the page to load
- 2. get the form to load
- 3. get the form submission to work and simply show "Success" or "Failure"
- 4. finally, write the send_sms function (you've almost done it)

Answer (score 0):

Lets start from the dust cloud.

What you are asking is mostly about how the web pages work. You need to know how to pass parameters using HTML. There are lots of ways to do it. But with django there is a pattern.

You need a url, and a view to catch any requests. Then you need to create a template and a form inside it. With this form you could create some requests to send data to your view.

To create you need to edit urls.py inside your project add an url:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from my_app.views import my_view

urlpatterns = [
    ...

    url(r'^my_url$', my_view, name='my_view')
    ...
]
```

For more about urls please look at [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/) page at documentation.

Then create your view inside your app which is my_app in my example. Edit my_app/views.py

my_app/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
     return HttpResponse('IT WORKS!')
```

This way you get a working view which could be accessed with path `/my_url`. If you run `./manage.py runserver` you could access your view from `http://localhost:8000/my_url`.

To create a form you need to create a template. By default django searches app directories for templates. Create a templates directory in your app, in our case `my_app/templates` and create an HTML file inside. For example `my_app/templates/my_form.html`. But i advice to create one more directory inside templates directory. `my_app/templates/my_app/my_form.html`. This will prevent template conflicts. You can check [Templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/) page at documentation for more.

my_app/templates/my_app/my_form.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="/my_url" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" name="number">
      <input type="text" name="message">
      <input type="submit" value="Run My Code">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the one of the ways of creating your form. But I **do not** recommend it. I will make it prettier. But first lets "Make it work", edit your views.py:

> **csrf_token** is a django builtin template tag, to put CSRF token into your form. By default django requires CSRF tokens at every post
>   request.

my_app/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render('my_app/my_form.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        # get post parameters or None as default value
        number = request.POST.get('number', None)
        message = request.POST.get('message', None)

        # check if parameters are None or not
        if number is None or message is None:
            return HttpResponse('Number and Message should be passed')

        # your code goes here
        ...

        return HttpResponse('Your code result')
```

Till this point the purpose of this answer was "Making it work". Lets convert it nice and clean. First of all we would create **Form**. Forms are like models, which helps you create forms as objects. It also handles form validations. Forms are saved inside forms directory generally. Create `my_app/forms.py` and edit it:

my_app/forms.py

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    number = forms.CharField(max_length=15, required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(max_length=160, required=True)
```

Put your form inside your template:

my_app/templates/my_app/my_form.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="{% url 'my_view' %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form }}
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Besides the form, the action of the HTML form tag is also changed.
>   **url** template tag is used to get url form url name specified in urls.py.
>   Instead of url tag, `{{ request.path }}` could have been used.

Create a form instance and pass it to the template rendering:

my_app/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import MyForm

def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = MyForm()
        return render('my_app/my_form.html', {'form': form})
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)

        # check if for is not valid
        if not form.is_valid():
            # return same template with the form
            # form will show errors on it.
            return render('my_app/my_form.html', {'form': form})

        # your code goes here
        ...

        return HttpResponse('Your code result')
```

You can use class based vies to write your view, but it's not necessary. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view that takes up query parameters from the url and use it for further implementation. Then you can create a link/button in the html template which can redirect you to that url. For example:

in urls.py:

```
url(r'^run_a/(?P<msg>\w{0,25})/(?P<num>\w{0,25})/$', yourcode, name='get_msg'),
```

in template:

```
<a href="{% url 'get_msg' message number %}">submit</a>
```

in views.py:

```
def get_msg(request,msg,num):
     message=msg
     number=num
     #rest of the code
```

Hope this helps :)